# Filterable RecyclerView expecting variable initialisation

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, listadapter

After trying to implement filterable functionality for my RecyclerView, I'm a bit confused as to what way is best to resolve this error and warning.

I have considered using this:

```
private var productListFull: List<Product> = ArrayList(productList)
```

but I'm not sure that is correct, considering the different properties

**Error**

> `productListFull` must be initialised

**Warning**

> `private var productListFull: List<Product>` can be joined with assignment

```
class MyListAdapter(private val mCtx: Context, private val productList: MutableList<Product>, private val mTwoPane: Boolean) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder>(), Filterable {
    private var productListFull: List<Product>

    private val productFilter = object : Filter() {
        override fun performFiltering(constraint: CharSequence?): Filter.FilterResults {
            val filteredList = ArrayList<Product>()

            when {
                constraint == null || constraint.isEmpty() -> filteredList.addAll(productListFull)
                else -> {
                    val filterPattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim { it <= ' ' }

                    for (item in productListFull) {
                        when {
                            item.productName!!.toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern) -> filteredList.add(item)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            val results = Filter.FilterResults()
            results.values = filteredList

            return results
        }

        override fun publishResults(constraint: CharSequence, results: Filter.FilterResults) {
            productList.clear()
            productList.addAll(results.values as List<Product>)
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }

    inner class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var textviewTitle: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.listitem_title)
        var textviewSubtitle: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.listitem_subtitle)
    }

    init {
        productListFull = ArrayList(productList)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx)
        val v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, parent, false)
        return MyViewHolder(v)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return productList.size
    }

    override fun getFilter(): Filter {
        return productFilter
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the warning, if you put the cursor at the line that gives this warning and  press Alt+Enter, a menu will appear and if you choose **"Join declaration and assignment"** then you will see that the `init { }` constructor disappear and the line change to this:

```
private var productListFull: List<Product> = ArrayList(productList)
```

meaning the assignment that was inside the `init { }` constructor, joined with the declaration.
This is more a Java than a Kotlin way to initialize a list and you should also change the declaration from `List<Product>` to `ArrayList<Product>`. But **you don't need that**.

You must change this line

```
private var productListFull: List<Product>
```

which only declares the list but it does not initialize it

to this:

```
private var productListFull = productList.toMutableList()
```

to copy all the elements of `productList` to `productListFull` and now you must delete the `init { }` constructor which is not needed any more.